# Undefined Element Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, shuffle

I have a problem. When I shuffle a array starting from position 1 and ending on position 49, one element seems to be undefined when outputted in the console.

```
for (var i = 49; i > 0; i--) {
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  var temp = genNr[i];
  genNr[i] = genNr[j];
  genNr[j] = temp;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: what's in genNr before this function manipulates it?

Comment: You need to provide the loop surrounding the loop you have posted... which I am guessing is indexed using `j` and where `genNr` array is initialised? This is likely an index out of bounds issue!

Comment: How many elements are in the array? In other words, where does `49` come from?

Comment: genNr is initialised at the top. Here is the full script http://pastebin.com/cJJ4Gy9u

Comment: @Pointy 49 is the lenght of the array. The array start with position 1

Comment: Arrays start at `0` in JavaScript. If the length is `49`, the last element is at index `48` not `49`.

Comment: Well if you want to go from `1` to `49` that works of course, but your `Math.random()` expression can sometimes return zero.

Comment: @Pointy Oh well, that`s the problem ! Thank you very mutch. Solved it !

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that `genNr` contains 49 elements. The first time the loop runs, `i` will be 49 so you're trying to access `genNr[49]`. But, since array indexes start at zero, `genNr[49]` is undefined.

You need to start the loop with `i` equal to the length of the array minus 1, and stop when `i` is less than zero.

```
for (var i = genNr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  var temp = genNr[i];
  genNr[i] = genNr[j];
  genNr[j] = temp;
}
```